# Continuous saving files to directory after manual removal of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I created a GUI project in pyqt5 that lets us enter a country's name in the text input field, then we are getting data from the CoVid-19 API for the particular country. I added a feature (button) which give us a possibility to save matplotlib's plot with statistics from API to my folder called "stats". Let's assume that I enter USA, download the pdf. It's ok. Then I enter Germany, download the pdf. It's ok, I got USA.pdf and Germany.pdf in /stats/, but if I remove 2 of them and enter third country, let's say Canada and click download button, it creates Canada.pdf and also USA and Germany again. I do not know when I made a mistake, but I am thinking of passing lambda function to "clicked" event as a parameter has something to do with that. Here is the code:

**App.py**

```
def create_download_btn(self, data):
    self.download_btn.show()
    self.download_btn.move(320, 30)
    self.download_btn.resize(140, 40)
    self.download_btn.setText('Download PDF')
    self.download_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.create_pdf_plot(data))
    self.download_btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: #fff;'
                                    'color: #777;'
                                    'border-style: outset;'
                                    'border-width: 3px;'
                                    'border-color: rgb(220, 20, 60);'
                                    'border-radius: 5px;'
                                    'font-size: 16px;'
                                    'font-weight: bold;'
                                    'padding: 5px;')

def create_pdf_plot(self, data):
    export_to_pdf(data)
    self.download_btn.hide()
    self.create_download_label()
    self.download_label.setText(f"You've downloaded the file successfully!\n "
                                 f"Path: /stats/{data[-1]['Country']}.pdf")
```

**create_pdf.py**

```
def export_to_pdf(data):
"""
Creating and exporting plot to a PDF file basing on the given data.
:param data: Number of total cases, deaths, active cases, fetched from the API
:return: void
"""

days = np.array([])
confirmed_cases = np.array([])
deaths = np.array([])
active_cases = np.array([])

# Looping over every index of JSON data
for day, data_elem in enumerate(data):
    days = np.append(days, day)
    confirmed_cases = np.append(confirmed_cases, data_elem['Confirmed'])
    deaths = np.append(deaths, data_elem['Deaths'])
    active_cases = np.append(active_cases, data_elem['Active'])

# Creating a plot
plt.plot(days, confirmed_cases, color='black', label='Confirmed cases', linewidth=3)
plt.plot(days, deaths, color='red', label='Deaths', linewidth=3)
plt.plot(days, active_cases, color='green', label='Active cases', linewidth=3)
plt.title(f"{data[-1]['Country']} COVID-19 statistics")

# Creating and displaying table in a program's console using pandas
table = [['Numbers', confirmed_cases[-1], deaths[-1], active_cases[-1]]]
df_table = pd.DataFrame(table)
df_table.columns = (f"{data[-1]['Country']}", 'Confirmed cases', 'Deaths', 'Active cases')
print(df_table)

# Setting axis and saving the plot to a PDF file
plt.xlabel('Days since the first confirmed case')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(f"./stats/{data[-1]['Country']}.pdf")
plt.clf()
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the essential part that shows the problem. That is, you can get rid of most, if not all of your plotting code (just save a one-line text file; it will likely have the same issue). Then, make sure your code is actually executable: currently, start-up code for PyQT5 and your script in general is missing. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems you `connect`ed a new action(download) without un-`connect`ing the old action, hence clicking it makes it create all three files.(I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't use PYQT5 often and I'm not 100% of the API.

Comment: @xkcdjerry Thank you very much. `self.download_btn.disconnect()` at the very end of create_pdf function worked :)

Comment: OK,I'm going to post it as an answer if it worked XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `connect`ed a new action(download new country's pdf file) without un-`connect`ing the old action(download old country's pdf file), hence clicking it will trigger *all* the actions. Which makes it create all three files.
You can remove the `connect`ion after you're done with it to solve the bug.

Edit:
You can use `self.download_btn.disconnect()` to remove the `connect`ion.